# javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded for aes decryption

Tags: java

BadPadding Exception.

Given final block not properly padded for aes decryption: 
javax.crypto.BadPaddingException

code follows below

```
try
    {
        String val[];
        String text="";
        if(get.contains(","))
        {
            val=get.split(",");
            text=val[0];
        }
        else
        {
            text = get;
        }
        pubtxt2.setText(""+text.length());
        String key=cipkey;
        Key aesKey = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes(), "AES");
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, aesKey);
        byte sam[]=hextobin(text);
        String decrypted = new String(cipher.doFinal(sam));
        output.setText(decrypted);
        chk=decrypted;
        pubtxt3.setText(""+chk.length());
        a2++;
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.err.println(e);
    }
```

Comment: According to the documentation https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/crypto/Cipher.html

BadPaddingException - if this cipher is in decryption mode, and (un)padding has been requested, but the decrypted data is not bounded by the appropriate padding bytes

Comment: so what should i do?

Comment: PadPaddingException usually occurs when the key or the cipher text is wrong/defect. As AES can not recognize that something is wrong and it is decrypting garbage but at the end the padding algorithm checks the padding bytes and recognizes something is wrong. Additionally you should make sure you are sing the correct padding algorithm.